# ASP.NET web server having issues with HTTPS -- Chrome Only

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, ssl, https, termination

Okay, so at my work we are moving the SSL Termination from the web server to the load balancer.  The load balancer then passes the request on to the server with a flag set indicating that the connection is to be secure.

We are having absolutely no issues with every browser (IE, FF, Safari) except Chrome.  Oh, Chrome, you wascally wabbit, you.

So I don't actually suspect Chrome to be having issues, but rather the server.  I'm thinking Chrome must be sending some sort of different header values that are causing the server to freak out.  I get this message from chrome, after sending the request and waiting for a response:

- Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

In fact, after telling Fiddler2 to capture HTTPS CONNECTs (acts as a proxy between the browser and the server), I get a response back successfully.  So again, it would seem that Chrome is sending something that the server doesn't find favorable.

Any ideas what I should check?  I'm kind of at a loss.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It is either the server or the load balancer. I would suspect the later, which may make it hard to debug. I assume you are using Fiddler to capture the Chrome traffic, right? And, are you saying you can then successfully send the same request that Chrome sent and have it succeed? If so, Chrome is not properly handling the redirect? Just an idea.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the thoughts Gregory.  After setting up debugging on the server, I've confirmed that the load balancer is the one having issues.  The HTTPS request never gets to the server when sent from Chrome.  Every other request (HTTP, or HTTPS from other browsers) arrives at the server successfully.  Luckily/Unluckily for me, I can't touch the load balancer -- I'll have to have ops take a look.  Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: If you'd like, I can mark an answer as the official one, if you care about the points.

Comment: For anyone wondering what the fix was, apparently there is a new protocol or something (sorry for lack of specifics, it's been a while since we moved on from this issue) that new load balancers are capable of handling.  We had an old load balancer, and that was causing the issues with Chrome (only with Chrome..).  We upgraded the hardware and our issues went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering what the fix was, apparently there is a new protocol or something (sorry for lack of specifics, it's been a while since we moved on from this issue) that new load balancers are capable of handling. We had an old load balancer, and that was causing the issues with Chrome (only with Chrome..).